# Why getting SSLCertVerificationError ... self signed certificate in certificate chain - from one machine but not another?

Tags: certificate, trust

I am trying to test an API on my site.  The tests work just fine from one machine, but running the code from a different machine results in the SSLCertVerificationError - which is odd because the site has an SSL cert and is NOT self signed.

Here is the core of my code:

```
async def device_connect(basename, start, end):
    url = SERVER_URL
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        post_tasks = []
        # prepare the coroutines that post
        for x in range(start, end):
            myDevice={'test':'this'}
            post_tasks.append(do_post(session, url, myDevice))
        # now execute them all at once
        await asyncio.gather(*post_tasks)

async def do_post(session, url, data):
    async with session.post(url, data =data) as response:
          x = await response.text()
```

I tried (just for testing) to set 'verify=False' or trust_env=True, but I continue to get the same error.  On the other computer, this code runs fine and no trust issue results.

Answer (score 0):

That error text is somewhat misleading. OpenSSL, which python uses, has dozens of error codes that indicate different ways certificate validation can fail, including

- X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN -- the peer's cert can't be chained to a root cert in the local truststore; the chain received from the peer includes a root cert, which is self-signed (because root certs *must* be self-signed), but that root is not locally trusted

  Note this is not talking about the peer/leaf cert; if *that* is self signed and not trusted, there is a *different* error X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT which displays as just 'self signed certificate' *without* the part about 'in certificate chain'.
- X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY (displays in text as 'unable to get local issuer certificate') -- the received chain does not contain a self-signed root *and* the peer's cert can't be chained to a locally trusted root

In both these cases the important info is **the peer's cert doesn't chain to a trusted root**; whether the received chain includes a self-signed root is less important. It's kind of like if you go to your doctor and after examination in one case s/he tells you "you have cancer, and the weather forecast for tomorrow is a bad storm" or in another case "you have cancer, but the weather forecast for tomorrow is sunny and pleasant". While these are in fact slightly different situations, and you might conceivably want to distinguish them, you need to focus on the part about "you have cancer", not tomorrow's weather.

So, *why* doesn't it chain to a trusted root? There are several possibilities:

1. the server is sending a cert chain with a root that SHOULD be trusted, but machine F is using a truststore that does not contain it. Depending on the situation, it might be appropriate to add that root cert to the default truststore (affecting at least all python apps unless specifically coded otherwise, and often other types of programs like C/C++ and Java also) or it might be better to customize the truststore for your appplication(s) only; or it might be that F is already customized wrongly and just needs to be fixed.
2. the server is sending a cert chain that actually uses a bad CA, but machine W's truststore has been wrongly configured (again either as a default or customized) to trust it.
3. machine F is not actually getting the real server's cert chain, because its connection is 'transparently' intercepted by something. This might be something authorized by an admin of the network (like an IDS/IPS/DLP or captive portal) or machine F (like antivirus or other 'endpoint security'), or it might be something very bad like malware or a thief or spy; or it might be in a gray area like some ISPs (try to) intercept connections and insert advertisements (at least in data likely to be displayed to a person like web pages and emails, but these can't always be distinguished).
4. the (legit) server is sending different cert chains to F (bad) and W (good). This could be intentional, e.g. because W is on a business' internal network while F is coming in from the public net; however you describe this as 'my site' and I assume you would know if it intended to make distinctions like this. OTOH it could be accidental; one fairly common cause is that many servers today use SNI (Server Name Indication) to select among several 'certs' (really cert chains and associated keys); if F is too old it might not be sending SNI, causing the server to send a bad cert chain. Or, some servers use different configurations for IPv4 vs IPv6; F could be connecting over one of these and W the other.

To distinguish these, and determine what (if anything) to fix, you need to look at what certs are actually being received by both machines.

- If you have (or can get) OpenSSL on both, do `openssl s_client -connect host:port -showcerts`. For OpenSSL 1.1.1 up (now common) to *omit* SNI add `-noservername`; for older versions to *include* SNI add `-servername host`. Add `-4` or `-6` to control the IP version, if needed. This will show subject and issuer names (`s:` and `i:`) for each received cert; if any are different, and especially the last, look at #3 or #4. If the names are the same compare the whole base64 blobs to make sure they are entirely the same (it *could* be a well-camoflauged attacker). If they are the same, look at #1 or #2.
- Alternatively, if policy and permissions allow, get network-level traces with Wireshark or a more basic tool like tcpdump or snoop. In a development environment this is usually easy; if either or both machine(s) is production, or in a supplier, customer/client, or partner environment, maybe not. Check SNI in ClientHello, and in TLS1.2 (or lower, but nowadays lower is usually discouraged or prohibited) look at the Certificate message received; in wireshark you can drill down to any desired level of detail. If both your client(s) and server are new enough to support TLS1.3 (and you can't configure it/them to downgrade) the Certificate message is encrypted and wireshark won't be able to show you the contents unless you can get at least one of your endpoints to export the session secrets in SSLKEYLOGFILE format.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response!  It turns out the first computer only tests through a verification depth of 2, whereas the second computer tests to a verification depth of 3, resulting in the following:                                                                                                
depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self-signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
In reading elsewhere I read 'Root certificates issued by CAs are just self-signed certificates'...?

Comment: Root certs _are_ selfsigned, as I said in my first bullet, but to be clear most selfsigned certs are not roots. I asked you to look at the received chains; we already knew the verification result is different, but that could occur because of different received chains _or_ the same chain with different truststores, and you need to look _at the chain_ to determine which.